# How can I deploy Mobile Application Framework (MAF) in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, oracle-maf

How can I deploy Oracle-MAF in Android Studio?

I googled it a lot, but without avail. [The only way](http://go.sap.com/documents/2015/08/e6b6e820-5a7c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.html) I have found seems hard. Is there something easier?

Comment: The PDF you've linked too doesn't appear to be for Oracle Mobile Application Framework (MAF), but a SAP solution.  Assuming you're looking for an Oracle solution, this is probably why the SAP PDF seems hard ;-)  Assuming you do mean Oracle MAF, can you explain why you're attempting to achieve this?  Specifying the context of your question may reveal an easier route to what you want to achieve.

Comment: Do you want to run the Oracle-MAF in android platform?

Comment: @ChrisMuir, I develop an Android application and I used to do it in Android Studio.

Comment: Typically you would develop an Oracle-MAF app in JDeveloper & deploy to Android from there using the Android SDK, or iOS on Mac via Xcode. As Android Studio has no idea of the many features of MAF, it provides little to no benefit for maintaining a MAF app besides possible edge-case debugging scenarios.

Comment: Another option is the Eclipse version of MAF known as OEPE.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps .

### Steps

1. Install android studio  and create a new project (this is to enable emulator)
2. In `jDeveloper` Preference select `Mobile Application Framework`, select `Android platform.
3. Set `Android SDK Location, Android Platform Location, Android Build Tools Location`.
4. Generate Keystore entries.
5. Create one Deployment profile for Android (You can debug in simulator or run within your device).
6. Run/ Debug the application

Comment: This will run the Oracle MAF application in android platform

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm talking about developing application in Android Studio. Without JDeveloper, if possible

Comment: MAF is supported in JDeveloper and Eclipse only.

Comment: Yeah...! . Its true